# iTunes Store API -- sorting by popularity

Tags: api, sorting, itunes

Is it possible to search the [iTunes Store API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) and sort results by popularity?

If not, what is the next best alternative? Screen-scraping the [iTunes Preview](http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/jack-johnson/id909253?ign-mpt=uo%3D4) pages?

Comment: Did you read the page you linked to? There's nothing there that would say yes.

Comment: I did, I'm just hoping that someone may know of a non-mentioned parameter of some sort.

Answer (score -4):

Here is the steps for your problem
you need to make two file.

1) Wrapper file for itune API like "tune.php"

2) file form retrive the results "get_result_from_api.php"

**step 1 : Get Api url****

make sure that your itune api work properly

**for e.g.**

enter code here

$authentic_api = $this->endpointurl . '?api_key=' . $this->api_key . '&method=' . 'aj.jobs.search' . '&keywords=' . $this->keywords . '&location=' . $this->location. '&perpage=' . $this->perpage ;

echo $authentic_api;

**OUTPUT:**

http://www.authenticjobs.com/api/?api_key=3fb9a030d223ac8bb06eb07fea846182&method=aj.jobs.search&keywords=&location=&perpage=100

check your output api in new tab and make sure that it displays the results in XML format or HTML format

Step 2: Store the api results in XML or HTML format vice-verse..

**e.g.**

$xmlstr = @file_get_contents( $authentic_api );

if( !$xmlstr == null )

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement( $xmlstr );

if( empty($xml) || $xml == null )

return null;

$this->aj_results = $xml;

return $xml;

Step 3 : Parse your xml or html results
Parse results to get the selected data.
And store it in the array and return values to  "get_result_from_api.php"

step 4: Print is out 
using the foreach loop you need to print out the results that you get form the wrapper class..

Hope this things helps you out.

Because *"Hope is the Good thing, MAy be the best of the things, And no good things ever dies!"*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow JackLB!  [Signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) and [self-promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) are frowned upon, but you are encouraged to put these on your user page.  Be sure to read about [formatting posts](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as well.